# How to get the current dev_appserver version?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I get the GAE SDK to tell me what version it is?  I could not find anything like this:

```
dev_appserver.py --version
```

Note that this is different from `os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']`, which returns the application version, and it seems that `os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` always returns `Development/1.0` when I run it inside the Interactive Console.

I would like to create a GAE SDK updater script that performs the following logic:

1. Checks to see what the [latest version of GAE SDK for Python on Linux](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) is (as of this writing 1.7.5 which is available for download at https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/deprecated/175/google_appengine_1.7.5.zip.
2. Checks the currently installed version of the GAE SDK.
3. If the available version > installed version, downloads the latest package and unzips it into the correct directory.

If there is no "supported" way to do step #1, I am willing to hard-code the "latest version" in the script, but I still only want to download/install it once even if the script itself is run multiple times.  In other words, the script should be idempotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory where the GAE SDK zip is unpacked to contains a VERSION file with the following contents:

```
release: "1.7.5"
timestamp: 1357690550
api_versions: ['1']
```

So I wrote a script to pull the version out of there:

```
#!/bin/sh

INSTALLEDVERSION=`cat /usr/local/google_appengine/VERSION | grep release | cut -d: -f 2 | cut -d\" -f 2`
LATESTVERSION="1.7.5"

if [ $INSTALLEDVERSION != $LATESTVERSION ]; then
        echo "Update GAE SDK"
fi
```

Or, you can use this to obtain the version string on non-default installs, but `readlink` may not work correctly on Linux:

```
INSTALLEDDIR=`which dev_appserver.py | xargs readlink | xargs dirname`
INSTALLEDVERSION=`cat $INSTALLEDDIR/VERSION | grep release | cut -d: -f 2 | cut -d\" -f 2`
```

But this still does not provide a way to perform step 1, which would query the web for the latest version and do auto-updating.